# Yii2 attempts to re-apply old migration files

Tags: yii2, migration

I am sure this is something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Earlier today I updated my Yii2 installation to latest development version. After I completed my testing I decided to roll it back to stable release.
When composer failed to roll back, I deleted everything under `/VENDOR` directory as well as `composer.lock` and ran `composer update`.

**Issue:**
Now I can't use `php yii migrate`, as it says that I have to apply very first migration for user table named `m130524_201442_int`.
However, when I run `php yii migrate/history all` it shows that it was completed before:

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.10)

Total 17 migrations have been applied before:
    (2016-12-06 22:15:37) m161206_214310_rts_detail_type_enum2int
    (2016-12-06 22:15:36) m161206_210705_rts_types
    (2016-12-03 01:32:34) m161203_012757_emaillayout
    (2016-11-18 19:59:15) m161118_195401_rts_reimbursment
    (2016-11-18 17:48:24) m161118_172654_program
    (2016-11-18 04:51:38) m161118_043442_duedata_droptime
    (2016-11-17 20:05:40) m161117_200352_default_wo_tasks
    (2016-11-16 21:40:27) m161116_212528_defaultdates
    (2016-11-16 18:15:19) m161116_180722_defaulttasks
    (2016-11-14 22:40:05) m161114_221144_distribution
    (2016-11-14 20:26:09) m161114_202027_responsibility
    (2016-11-14 19:36:02) m161114_192729_distribution
    (2016-11-09 20:33:19) m161109_191955_locks2
    (2016-11-09 17:13:40) m161109_170126_rts_timing_impl
    (2016-11-09 17:13:39) m161011_171958_resp_list
    (2016-10-07 05:29:35) m161007_051543_locks
    (2016-08-04 15:57:58) m130524_201442_int
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I decided to push my code to another test server. Upon pulling new code from Git, I attempted to run `php yii migrate` which exited with: `No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date.`

After that I ran `composer update` because `composer.json` and `composer.lock` were pulled with this update. Composer finished running installing bunch of components, but did not change Yii2 version. I ran the `php yii migrate` and it exited with the same message: `No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date.`

This makes me think that something is wrong with my development server.

Any ideas on what it can be? I can rebuild dev server, but this puzzle is bugging me.

I appreciate any input you guys have.

Comment: Have you got by any chance modified `migrationNamespaces` and/or `migrationPath` properties of `MigrateController`?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply.

No, I did not make any modifications to my `MigrateController` not I messed with `migrationNamespaces` and/or `migrationPath`.

Comment: This is really interesting but requires debugging on the actual code. You need to check what is happening in the `getNewMigrations()` method of `BaseMigrateController` on this buggy environment.

Comment: Ok, one question. If you attempt to use `yii migrate` command, you get `No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date`? If yes, I will then answer with 1 solution I know.

Comment: Dev server: `yii migrate` - attempts to apply `m130524_201442_int`

Tst server: `yii migrate` - returns `No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date`.

Both servers already have *all* migrations applied.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite comfortable how Yii2's migration works since even if you make changes to migration files, migration system will not detect that. To remove

> No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date

message and re-apply new migration files, you need to go to database and search for auto-generated table. It's called something like `base_migration` (or just `migration`).

You will see that it contains information about applied migrations - **version** (file name) and **apply time**. Remove all rows from that table.

After you have removed all rows, migration system will no longer detect any applied changes before and will take all files that are found in `migration` folder.